# VIM solarized colorscheme on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vim, color-scheme

I'm using vim on ubuntu 14.10 and i installed solarized colorscheme to my vim but the color not looks like what it should to be, this is what i get >>
[image]

this is my **.vimrc** file https://github.com/adham90/vim/blob/master/vimrc

what can i do to fix it?!

Comment: Can you include the contents of your vimrc file?

Comment: https://github.com/adham90/vim/blob/master/vimrc

Comment: I don't think the solzarized theme is meant for terminal vim use.  Terminals are limited to 256 colors, which means that color schemes that use more than 256 colors look wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also try adding `TERM='xterm-256color'` to your bashrc.

The vim wiki has a [guide on installing 256-color schemes](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_in_vim).

Comment: okay i do that but i'm using zsh so i add zsh-256color plugin,i think it do the same, so when i use "se bg=light" it work fine but with dark bg, it is not the same color as solarized dark

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your `.vimrc` file with the following:

```
" ==== colorscheme ====
syntax enable
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized
" =====================
```